# How to select record from database based on condition

Tags: asp.net-core

With the below lines of code l can load data from the database in descending order

```
    public IActionResult UrlDatasource([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
    {
        IEnumerable DataSource = _context.Customer.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNo).ToList();
        DataOperations operation = new DataOperations();            
        return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource}) : Json(DataSource);
    }
```

I want to load data from database where status column is Inactive using the sql statement in the about linq, but l don't know how to do it. Please assist me.

| Id | Customer | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | Active |
| 2 | Jane | Active |
| 3 | Vicky | Inactive |
| 4 | Anna | Active |

Expected Output

| Id | Customer | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Vicky | Inactive |

Comment: Are you just looking for [the `.Where()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)?

Comment: There are 2 approaches for this. For linq you can filter using .Where() or can use raw sql with dapper to filter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to load data from database where status column is Inactive
> using the sql statement in the about linq, but l don't know how to do
> it. Please assist me.

Well, according to your description and shared code snippet seems like your `status` property or entity is the type of string.

If you would like to filter data based on the `status` property you could simply include [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0) clause and then execute your order and finally bind the list.

For subsequent SQL you could write the query as following:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Status
FROM [Customer]
WHERE [Status] = 'Inactive'
ORDER BY [Id] DESC;
```

Linq Query:

```
 var inactiveCustomers = _Context.Where(x => x.Status == "Inactive").OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Full Sample Code:

Mode:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    List<CustomerModel> _Context = new List<CustomerModel>()
            {
                new CustomerModel { Id = 1, Name = "John", Status = "Active" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 2, Name = "Alice", Status = "Inactive" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 3, Name = "Bob", Status = "Inactive" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 4, Name = "Eva", Status = "Active" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 5, Name = "Mike", Status = "Active" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 6, Name = "Sophia", Status = "Inactive" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 7, Name = "Liam", Status = "Active" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 8, Name = "Olivia", Status = "Active" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 9, Name = "William", Status = "Inactive" },
                new CustomerModel { Id = 10, Name = "Emma", Status = "Active" }
            };

    var inactiveCustomers = _Context.Where(x => x.Status == "Inactive").OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();

    return View(inactiveCustomers);
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/walkthrough-writing-queries-linq), if you want to study more .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Where() "clause"

```
IEnumerable DataSource = _context.Customer
  .Where(w => w.Status == "Inactive") 
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNo).ToList();
```